# How to use a string in a Sql argument?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

How should go about inserting a string into a SQL argument?

Something like this:

```
string clas = "Computer Science";

sql = "SELECT * from STUDENTS where CLASS='clas'";
```

Comment: Beware of SQL injection. You should use _prepared statements_.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of doing this:

1. This is the preferred and more secure way. You can use prepared statements like this

```
string clas = "Computer Science";
sql = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Class=?";

// Prepare the request right here

preparedStatement.setString(1, clas);

// Execute the request down here
```

2. A simpler but much less secure option (it's vulnerable to SQL-Injections)

```
string clas = "Computer Science";
sql = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Class='" + clas + "'";
```

Comment: That's why I said the second option is preferred and more secure

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I changed the order

Comment: Thanks for the answers. atm im not going for anything secure. The second answer gives me this error: 
Error (active) E0413 no suitable conversion function from "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>" to "char *" exists
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Simple answer:**

You can just do as follows:

```cpp
string clas = "Computer Science";
sql = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Class='" + clas + "'";
```

**Good answer**:

But, we can do better than that. What if multiple value replacement needed, then what? See the code below, it can replace multiple strings. And also, you can write sql injection check if needed. And the best thing, you just have to call the `prepare()` function and you're done.

**Usage Instructions:**

Use **?** where you need to put a string. If there are *multiple string replacement* needed, put all the strings in order(as parameters) when calling prepare function. Also, notice prepare function call `prepare(sql, {param_1, param_2, param_3, ..., param_n})`.

**[Note: it'll work with c++11 and higher versions. It won't work with c++11 pre version. So, while compile it, use -std=c++11 flag with g++]**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <initializer_list>

using namespace std;


// write code for sql injection if you think
// it necessary for your program
// is_safe checks for sql injection
bool is_safe(string str) {
    // check if str is sql safe or not
    // for sql injection
    return true; // or false if not sql injection safe
}

void prepare(string &sql, initializer_list<string> list_buf) {
    int idx = 0;
    int list_size = (int)list_buf.size();
    
    int i = 0;
    for(string it: list_buf) {
        // check for sql injection
        // if you think it's necessary
        if(!is_safe(it)) {
            // throw error
            // cause, sql injection risk
        }

        if(i >= list_size) {
            // throw error
            // cause not enough params are given in list_buf
        }

        idx = sql.find("?", idx);
        if (idx == std::string::npos) {
            if(i < list_size - 1) {
                // throw error
                // cause not all params given in list_buf are used
            }
        }
        sql.replace(idx, 1, it);

        idx += 1; // cause "?" is 1 char
        i++;
    }
}

// now test it
int main() {
    string sql = "SELECT * from STUDENTS where CLASS=?";
    string clas = "clas";

    prepare(sql, {clas});

    cout << sql << endl;


    string sql2 = "select name from class where marks > ? or attendence > ?";
    string marks = "80";
    string attendence = "40";

    prepare(sql2, {marks, attendence});

    cout << sql2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[P.S.]: feel free to ask, if anything is unclear.